# Keeping common ids from multiple streams with rxjs?

Tags: firebase, rxjs, reactive-programming, nosql

I have 3 streams coming from firebase returning arrays of people ids :

- 1 stream that gives me all people living in texas
- 1 stream that gives me all people that are men
- 1 stream that gives me all people that have a dog

How can I merge them and only get male people that have a dog ids ?

**Is there an operator that can give me common ids from multiple streams ?**
I've looked [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) and I don't seem to find the correct operator for what I want to do.

I could merge them and use Distinct but it removes them instead of giving them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use combine latest and filter the arrays:

```
var menWithDogsFromTexas = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
  menIds, withDogsIds, fromTexasIds,
  (men, dogs, texas) => {
    return men
      .filter(menId => dogs.indexOf(menId) >= 0)
      .filter(menId => texas.indexOf(menId) >= 0);
  }
);
```

Here is a [jsbin that demonstrate it](http://jsbin.com/yibulo/edit?js,console), I even updated the texas ids dynamically to show it reflects in the result.

You didn't mention it but I assumed you want all men with dogs from texas. If not, just remove the last filter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!